# Validation form parameters given in Palantir workshop

Tags: typescript, foundry-workshop, palantir-foundry-api

We have a form in Palantir workshop that takes values and add them to a Ontology object. I have a task to validate the combination(userId, startdate, states) from the inputs given in the form, either they already exists or not. We have typescript function that gets called when we submit that form. I am completely new to Typescript. Could you please help me how to achieve this.

```
import {
    @OntologyEditFunction,
    LocalDate,
    Integer, 
    Users,
    Double,
    FunctionsMap, 
    Function,
} from "@foundry/functions-api";
import {
    Objects, 
    ObjectSet,
    ObjectWeUse,
} from "@foundry/ontology-api";
@OntologyEditFunction()
public async createSkus(
  userId: string,
  is_Sku_Pending?: string,
  partition?: string,
  startdate?: LocalDate,
  all_states?: string,
  states?: string[], //selects multiples values
): Promise<void> {
        let final_states;
        
        if (all_states && all_states === "All") {
            final_states = U.all_usa_states; // A pre defined const string array
        } else if (all_states && all_states === "All but UT") {
            final_states = U.all_usa_states_without_utah; // A pre defined const string array
        } else {
            final_states = states;
        }
for (let i = 0; i < packages.length; i++) {
            let sku= Objects.create().ObjectWeUse(U.uuidv4());
            sku.userId= U.uuidv4();
            sku.states= final_states;
            sku.strs = startdate;
            sku.partition = partition
            sku.isSkuPending = is_Sku_Pending;
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow Shiva. As it stands this question is too vague, I would recommend that you reframe the question to focus into what you are concretely trying to achieve. If the problem is Typescript knowledge, there are many tutorials in the web to learn from. Here is a link to a random one I found on google https://www.educative.io/blog/typescript-tutorial . But you shouldn't ask "do the work for me" type questions here. If you wish to understand more of stackoverflow this is a good read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402293/is-stack-overflow-a-good-place-for-self-learners

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to validation for Actions in Foundry:

1. Action [Submission Criteria](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/action-types/submission-criteria/), which are available for *all* Action types and allow you to configure complex, user-facing submission validations with custom user feedback messages. These are the preferred way to validate criteria and give feedback to users. Within the configuration, you can reference any of the input parameters supplied by the user and also any of the *properties* of object parameters. This should be more than expressive enough to implement the check that you're looking to make.
2. Within *Function-backed* Actions, (and indeed any Function), you can throw a [user-facing error](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/functions/user-facing-error/), which will prevent the Function from executing and provide an error message to the user. This can be used to check for criteria that might only be accessible at Function execution-time, but is a worse user experience because the user fills out the form and clicks the button and only *then* receives the error message.

I'd recommend using the first approach.

Comment: I have tried first approach but I was able to check value of only one parameter but that too with other parameter or a specific value. I want to check a combination of parameters exists in object.
Equivalent SQL would be like:
 select count(*) from Object group by userId, startdate, states
And if the count is greater than 1 we should reject the submission.

Comment: @ShivaGolla what you described here, sounds like a better stack overflow question than how you elaborated above. My Recommendation is that you edit your question with these details, or open a new one

Comment: For this case, I'd recommend that you create some additional parameters in the Action that are explicitly for the purpose of validation, and then in your Worksop app (assuming you're integrating this Action into an application) I would use a Numeric Variable with the Object Set Aggregation to get the relevant numbers that you need (each in a different Variable). Then you can pass these into the Action and use them in the Submission Criteria.